# Getting String address in spinner instead of Strings form Array List in SQLite?

Tags: android, sqlite, spinner

Why am I getting address instead of values ?

I am fetching some data from Url and storing in SQLite.The data is in JSON format.

```
 DBHandlerMain.Class
  //.....some code

@Override
  public void addResults(Results detailDB) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    try {
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(KEY_ID, detailDB.getId());
        values.put(KEY_BOARD, detailDB.getmusic());         
        values.put(KEY_IMAGE, detailDB.getimage());
        db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, values);
        db.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("problem", e + "");
    }
}
 @Override
 public ArrayList<Results> getAllResults() {

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

    ArrayList<Results> cityList = null;
    try {
        cityList = new ArrayList<>();
        String QUERY = "SELECT DISTINCT  _images FROM " + TABLE_NAME;
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(QUERY, null);

        if (!cursor.isLast()) {
            while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
                Results all_results = new Results();
                all_results.setId(cursor.getInt(0));
                all_results.toString();
                cityList.add(all_results);
            }
        }

        db.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("error", e + "");
    }
    return cityList;
}
```

my_activity.class
     try {

```
            jsonarray = jsonobject.getJSONArray("results");

            for (int i = 0; i < jsonarray.length(); i++) {
                jsonobject = jsonarray.getJSONObject(i);
                Results results = new Results();
                results.setMusic(jsonobject.optString("music"));
                results.setImage(jsonobject.optString("image"));                  
                results.setId(jsonobject.getInt("id"));

                handler.addResults(results);
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

....some code

DBHandlerMain handler;

final ArrayList<Results> myList = handler.getAllResults();

 ArrayAdapter<Results> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,
           myList);

                   dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

        // attaching data adapter to spinner
        mySpinner.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
```

o/p : ...@1bc65f1

I tried to convert myList to string but the result is same.

```
ArrayList<String> newList = new ArrayList<String>(myList.size());

    for (Results myoldList : offlineList) {
        newList.add(String.valueOf(myoldList));
    }
```

Comment: Sorry, I did not get you.getAllResults is there. @PramodWaghmare

Comment: You want to see the o/p?

Comment: Yes. Because it may be helpful for solve your question

Comment: @G.I Joe how do you insert your data, show if possible ?

Comment: E/o/p: [com.Results@1bc65f1, com..Results@dad05d6, com.Results@3f6e057, com.Results@2c23744]

Comment: I updated question with insertion code @Nisarg

Comment: @G.IJoe addResults implementation ?

Comment: @G.IJoe i mean how do you bind your data in to model and save it to db !!!

Comment: handler.addResults(results); is in  my_activity class and addResults in DBHandlerMain. Results is my getter and setter class

Comment: @G.IJoe   show us that activity?

Comment: Which one.. my_activity and DBHandlerMain. are there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your method to convert object to string is wrong.

```
ArrayList<String> newList = new ArrayList<String>(myList.size());

for (Results myoldList : offlineList) {
    newList.add(String.valueOf(myoldList));
}
```

With this you are getting the string value of the objects identifier address. Your method should look like:

```
ArrayList<String> newList = new ArrayList<String>(myList.size());

for (Results myoldList : offlineList) {
    newList.add(myoldList.getMyObjectStringAttribute());
}
```

Where myoldList.getMyObjectStringAttribute() is the objects attribute you want to list.

Comment: The count is correct but the values are null @RicardoBarroca

Answer (score 0):

You are getting hash in the list because your `com.Result` class doesn't have a proper `toString` method. Implement a `toString` method in your `Result` class that returns the proper `String` property.